# How to get Ratings and Reviews on Facebook Check-ins place page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the Ratings and Reviews on Facebook Check-ins Place Page.

e.g.people's Rating and reviews for Disney Land(https://www.facebook.com/Disneyland/reviews)

I have searched on facebook developer website and Stack Overflow 
,some says i should query graph api like this`https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/ratings` after i get the **PAGE ACCESS TOKEN** by using this `https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/accounts`

Here is my Steps :

1.get an long lived AccessToken by using facebook4j

2.send query `https://graph.facebook.com/11081890741/accounts?access_token={my_access_token}`

But the server always return me an exception `"message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"`

I am really sure that I have select the "manage_pages" box.

what mistake did I make?

and please tell me how to modify the queries to get the data I want.

Thanks.

Comment: `11081890741` is the id of the Disneyland Facebook page – and pages to not have an `accounts` connection, only user accounts have. You need to ask a _user_ that has admin privileges for that FB page for `manage_pages` permission, and then query the `accounts` connection for that user to get a page access token. (So you will likely _not_ be able to get a page access token for the Disneyland page – which is kinda the point behind page access tokens, that they protect data _about_ the page from being accessed by just anyone …)

Comment: @CBroe: that would actually be a good answer, you should post it as one :) - my upvote shall be yours.

Comment: @luschn: OK, done that …

Answer (score 1):

`11081890741` is the id of the Disneyland Facebook page – and pages to not have an `accounts` edge, only user accounts have.

You need to ask a *user* that has admin privileges for that FB page for `manage_pages` permission, and then query the `accounts` edge for that user to get a page access token.

(So you will likely not be able to get a page access token for the Disneyland page – which is kinda the point behind page access tokens, that they protect data about the page from being accessed by just anyone …)